# "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" for jQuery droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want enable dragging elements and drop them in speciefied element container. But when I load my website, I get this in my console: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function ... presentation-categories.js?version=1:23`.

Line 23 is where `$( ".panel-body" ).droppable({` starts.

I tried to remove a whole `$( ".panel-body" ).droppable(...);` and then `draggable` works, but I need drop-container.

This is actual `presentation-categories.js`:

```
var dropped = false;

$( ".draggable-presentation" ).draggable({
  appendTo: ".my",
  zIndex: 999999999,
  placeholder: "sortable-placeholder",
  revert: true,
  cursorAt: {
    left: 67,
    top: 43
  },
  helper: function() {
    var presBackground = $(this).find('.slide').css('background');
    var presentationName = $(this).find('strong').html();
    var helper = $('<div class="slide-helper"></div>').html(presentationName).css({background: presBackground});
    return helper;
  }
});

$( ".panel-body" ).droppable({
  activeClass: "ui-state-default",
  hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
  accept: ".slideshowWindow, .draggable-presentation, .slide",
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    dropped = true;
  }
}).sortable();
```

PS: I have including both jQuery and jQuery-ui scripts right and also latest versions.

Comment: Could you show us your script tags, please? I know you said you included them correctly, but the most likely cause of this error is a problem there. "undefined is not a function" on line 23 suggests that `droppable` is not defined.

Comment: I am using `require.js`, so: `require(['jquery', 'jquery-ui'], function($) {`. It must be correct, because other jQuery-ui interactions work well.

Comment: Can you log the contents of $, as well as $('.panel-body').droppable?

Comment: `console.log($('document').sortable());` -> element selector and `console.log($('document').droppable());` -> TypeError. I don't know why, but both sortable and droppable are interactions of jQuery-ui.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same error message and i solved it by updating my jQuery UI javascript file.

Go to http://jqueryui.com/download and make sure the option "Droppable" is checked and click download.

You will now have a jQuery UI javascript file that includes the droppable functionality.

Comment: Sorry, I almost forgot your answer :D Yes I remember, that updating jQuery-UI worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was due to including `jquery` once again after included `jquery-ui`, So make sure `jquery` is included before `jquery-ui`.

Comment: I'm using requireJS, so jQuery is always loaded before jQuery-ui, but as I said in comment before, I just had to upgrade jQuery-ui to latest version. Now using CDN jQuery, so this should not happen again for me.